# Need help for json parsing in iPhone with UIPicker View

Tags: iphone, json, uipicker

AM newbiee to iPhone. I wanna to get the specific attributes in JSON output. Below is the JSON output: My requirement is to show "RATES" with corresponding Country codes in UIPicker. Could anyone help me please.

```
{
    "license": "License Agreement available at: http://openexchangerates.org/license/",
    "timestamp": 1361260808,
    "base": "USD",
    "rates": {
        "AED": 3.67274,
        "AFN": 51.9082,
        "ALL": 104.737376,
        "AMD": 406.549996,
        "ANG": 1.788975,
        "AOA": 95.945867,
        "ARS": 5.011293,
        "AUD": 0.9682,
        "AWG": 1.7901,
        "AZN": 0.7847
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually what is the issue ? You need to know how to parse the json or you need to know how to display the data ?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a dictionary.Get all the values from rates key in an array and load the picker view with that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSData *data = [yourjsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError*error;
NSDictionary *responseDict;
responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",[responseDict valueForKey:@"rates"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[[responseDict valueForKey:@"rates"] valueForKey:@"AED"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[responseDict valueForKey:@"timestamp"]);
```

it will help.